# Usage of Translate.setHttpReferrer();

Tags: java, google-translate

In Google Translate API, what is the use of `Translate.setHttpReferrer("")` ?

And what value should I give as a referrer String ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP referrer is the page from where the API request is being made. You should set the string value to the URL of the page you are using the Translate API.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2)

Comment: @SachinK if this helped you, please mark it as the answer